# Unity Engine - KeyNotFound Exception

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, iequalitycomparer

So, I've trying to make a 2D roguelike in Unity, I want to implement a pixel shadow based on sprites (I have a tile set containing all shadow tiles I may need), So I made that each Shadow had a "shadowType", to define either the shadow is coming from the top, bottom, etc. and I add them all to a Dictionary, with the keys being a 2x2 array (I had to declare a new class for the array), but when I try to call the ShadowType from the dictionary it gives a KeyNotFound Exception, I'd appreciate if I could get some help

ShadowObject script (apllied to all shadow prefabs):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ShadowObject : MonoBehaviour {

   public ShadowType shadowType;
}

public enum ShadowType 
{
    BottomEnd, Bottom, OutterCorner, Right, RightEnd, InnerConner, None
}
```

BoardObject script (for now only defines wether a object should cast shadows or not):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BoardObject : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool castShadow = false;
}
```

GameManager script (calls the board initialization):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    GameManager instance = null;
    BoardManager boardManager;

    void Awake () {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = this;
        else if (instance != this)
            Destroy (this);

        DontDestroyOnLoad (this);

        boardManager = GetComponent<BoardManager> ();
    }

    void Start () {
        boardManager.SetupsScene ();
    }
}
```

BoardManager script (Builds the Board, set ups the floor, walls and shadows):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

public class BoardManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public int width, height;
    Camera cam;

    public GameObject[] floorTiles;
    public GameObject mainFloorTile;
    public GameObject[] wallTiles;
    public List<GameObject> shadowTiles;

    Transform boardHolder;
    List<Vector3> gridPositions = new List<Vector3>();
    Dictionary<Vector3, GameObject> boardObjects = new Dictionary<Vector3, GameObject>();

    #region ShadowHandler

//for handling 2x2 spaces, needed to know which shadow to instantiate
    class Matrix2 <T> { 
        public T[,] elements = new T[2,2];
        public Matrix2 () {}
        public Matrix2 (T m00, T m01, T m10, T m11){
            elements[0,0] = m00;
            elements[0,1] = m01;
            elements[1,0] = m10;
            elements[1,1] = m11;
        }
    }

//I tought that using this with the dictionary could solve the problem, it didn't
    class Matrix2EqualityComparer <T>: IEqualityComparer<Matrix2<T>> {

        public bool Equals (Matrix2<T> m1, Matrix2<T> m2){
            if (m1 == null && m2 == null)
                return true;
            else if (m1 == null || m2 == null)
                return false;
            else if (m1.elements == m2.elements)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        public int GetHashCode (Matrix2<T> mat){
            return base.GetHashCode ();
        }
    }

    static Matrix2EqualityComparer<bool> mat2EqC = new Matrix2EqualityComparer<bool> ();
    Dictionary<Matrix2<bool>, ShadowType> shadowListOrganizer = new Dictionary<Matrix2<bool>, ShadowType>(mat2EqC);

//adds all 16 posible states of the boardObjects to the dictioanry, with the shadowType that should be instantiate in that case
    void SetupShadowListOrganizer () {
        shadowListOrganizer.Clear ();
        shadowListOrganizer.Add (new Matrix2<bool> (false, false, false, false), ShadowType.None);
        shadowListOrganizer.Add (new Matrix2<bool> (false, false, false, true), ShadowType.None);
        shadowListOrganizer.Add (new Matrix2<bool> (false, false, true, false), ShadowType.RightEnd);
        shadowListOrganizer.Add (new Matrix2<bool> (false, false, true, true), ShadowType.None);
        shadowListOrganizer.Add (new Matrix2<bool> (false, true, false, false), ShadowType.BottomEnd);
        shadowListOrganizer.Add (new Matrix2<bool> (false, true, false, true), ShadowType.None);
        shadowListOrganizer.Add (new Matrix2<bool> (false, true, true, false), ShadowType.InnerConner);
        shadowListOrganizer.Add (new Matrix2<bool> (false, true, true, true), ShadowType.None);
        shadowListOrganizer.Add (new Matrix2<bool> (true, false, false, false), ShadowType.OutterCorner);
        shadowListOrganizer.Add (new Matrix2<bool> (true, false, false, true), ShadowType.None);
        shadowListOrganizer.Add (new Matrix2<bool> (true, false, true, false), ShadowType.Right);
        shadowListOrganizer.Add (new Matrix2<bool> (true, false, true, true), ShadowType.None);
        shadowListOrganizer.Add (new Matrix2<bool> (true, true, false, false), ShadowType.Bottom);
        shadowListOrganizer.Add (new Matrix2<bool> (true, true, false, true), ShadowType.None);
        shadowListOrganizer.Add (new Matrix2<bool> (true, true, true, false), ShadowType.InnerConner);
        shadowListOrganizer.Add (new Matrix2<bool> (true, true, true, true), ShadowType.None);
    }

    #endregion

    void Awake () {
        cam = Camera.main;
        cam.orthographicSize = height > width ? ( height + 2) / 2 + 1: ( width + 2 ) / 2 + 1;
        cam.transform.position = new Vector3(width / 2, height / 2, -10f);
    }

    void InitialiseList() {
        gridPositions.Clear ();

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++){
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++){
                gridPositions.Add (new Vector3 (x, y, 0f));
            }
        }
    }

    void BoardSetup () {
        boardHolder = Instantiate (new GameObject ("BoardHolder").transform);

        for (int y = -1; y <= height; y++){
            for (int x = -1; x <= width; x++){
                GameObject toInstantiate = ( x == -1 || y == -1 || x == width || y == height ) ?
                    wallTiles[Random.Range (0, wallTiles.Length)] :
                    Random.Range(0, 101) <= 66 ?
                    mainFloorTile :
                    floorTiles[Random.Range (0, floorTiles.Length)];
                GameObject instance = Instantiate (toInstantiate, new Vector3 (x, y, 0f), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                instance.transform.SetParent (boardHolder);
                boardObjects.Add (new Vector3 (x, y, 0f), instance);
            }
        }
    }

    void SetupShadow () {
        SetupShadowListOrganizer ();

        for (int y = 0; y <= height; y++){ //this loop will go on for a 2x2 grid, with the (x, y) tile being the right bottom corner of that grid
            for (int x = 0; x <= width; x++){
                bool m00 = boardObjects[new Vector3 (x - 1, y + 1, 0f)].GetComponent<BoardObject>().castShadow;
                bool m01 = boardObjects[new Vector3 (x, y + 1, 0f)].GetComponent<BoardObject>().castShadow;
                bool m10 = boardObjects[new Vector3 (x - 1, y, 0f)].GetComponent<BoardObject>().castShadow;
                bool m11 = boardObjects[new Vector3 (x, y, 0f)].GetComponent<BoardObject>().castShadow;
                GameObject toInstantiate = shadowTiles.SingleOrDefault (shadow => shadow.GetComponent<ShadowObject> ().shadowType == shadowListOrganizer[new Matrix2<bool> (m00, m01, m10, m11)]);
                if (toInstantiate == null)
                    continue;
                GameObject instance = Instantiate (toInstantiate, new Vector3 (x, y, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
                instance.transform.SetParent (boardHolder);
            }
        }
    }

    public void SetupsScene () {
        InitialiseList ();
        BoardSetup ();
        SetupShadow ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't pass your comparer to your dictionary indexer.

Second, you can't do it since indexing is not comparision.

Third, it would not work anyway.

`object.Equals` returns result of `object.ReferenceEquals` for reference types. Two different objects have two different references (and you create new `Matrix2<T>` every time). Two different instances of `Matrix2<T>` have two different instances of `Matrix2<T>.elements`, and `==` operator on two `T[,]` objects calls for `Equals` method (which calls `ReferenceEquals`), as well.

You have to override `Matrix2<T>.Equals()` method and compare *content* of `Matrix2<T>.elements`. Handy way to do so is [Enumerable.SequenceEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx) extention method.

Comment: Already solved it, but thanks, since I wanted a way to store a 2 by 2 grid of boolean values I made so each tile got a number from 0 to 3, then , if it was true I would set a coeficients value for that tile to be 1, 0 otherwise, so I mulplied coeficient[i]*Mathf.Pow(2, i), so I would get a number between 0 and 15, then I added all posible states of the grid to the corresponding shadowType and made the ShadowListOrganizer an array instead of a dictioanry, so I could enter with the key I got from 0 to 15, it worked